# Setup exe file version when publishing with dotnet

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I have a net core consoleapp project, as follows (VS 2017 style):

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
    <Version>2.0.0</Version>
    <AssemblyVersion>3.0.0.0</AssemblyVersion>
    <FileVersion>4.0.0.0</FileVersion>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
    <RuntimeFrameworkVersion>1.0.4</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

I can build the project without any issues, I can publish it using dotnet publish -r win10-x64 and it will generate an exe file together with the dll file. My problem is that the exe file has some strange FileVersion and ProductVersion fields (in my case FileVersion = 1.0.1.4500 and ProductVersion 1.0.1.cee57... (some guid)). Also the rest of the file details (name, copyrights) are related to dotnet instead of my own project.

Is there any way I can control the exe details when publishing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, the main build output of your project still is a `.dll` file, the .exe (or linux, mac executables) file is a copied and renamed `dotnet.exe` (or in case of upcoming 2.0 versions, `apphost.exe` with the dll name to run embedded).

The exe file is only a helper that boots the runtime and then loads your dll. However, you can try to use binary editing tools like `editbin.exe` (VS C++ Tools) to modify the file after publishing.

Comment: fyi the exe file is just extracted from this NuGet package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/runtime.win7-x64.Microsoft.NETCore.DotNetHost/1.0.1
This allows building self-contained .net core applications that run on windows from a linux or Mac machine

Answer (score 0):

Dotnet core 3.0 added the functionality of versioning the shim exe during publish, like OP was expecting.  It should work out of the box now.  However that feature does not function if running builds on a Nanoserver based docker environment.

> warning NETSDK1074: The application host executable will not be
> customized because adding resources requires that the build be
> performed on Windows (excluding Nano Server)