# Publishing app for win10-x64 runtime, dll gets VersionInfo.cs file information and executable does not, why?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I am publishing dotnet core app like this:

```
call dotnet publish MyApp.csproj -c Release -o "%scriptDir%\..\dist\Publish\MyApp" -r win10-x64
```

My ".csproj" file includes this (VersionInfo.cs file):

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="..\VersionInfo.cs" Exclude="bin\**;obj\**;**\*.xproj;packages\**" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

It contains info like this:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("My Company")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright © My Company 2018")]
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark("My Company")]
```

And in the output "**MyApp.dll**" gets all of this information: versions, company name and etc. set in file properties.
But generated runtime executable "**MyApp.exe**" doesn't have any Version Info :(.

- Why doesn't the runtime contain the same info as the DLL?
- How do I add the info from the "VersionFile.cs" file to the specified runtime executable?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43516625/17034

Answer (score 1):

There is much easier way to include assembly information within project file.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <AssemblyVersion>1.0</AssemblyVersion>
    <FileVersion>1.0.0.0</FileVersion>
    <Company>My Company</Company>
    <Copyright>Copyright © My Company 2018</Copyright>
    <Trademark>My Company</Trademark>
</PropertyGroup>
```

As an example you can take a look into Newtonsoft.Json [project file](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Newtonsoft.Json.csproj).

[Here](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/6237#issuecomment-291408604) you can find some discussion about how .NET Core exe files are working.

Overall:

- .NET Core does not support exe files by design, only dll is generated
- If you specify runtime identifier during publish then native host (exe for windows) will be generated to boot managed dll for particular OS

Comment: I can totally agree on this answer. Don't use VersionInfo.cs with dotnet core

Comment: Main thing that I use this VersionFile in all projects, and there is there is "VersionUpdater" app which updates that VersionInfo.cs (Version and other details) and it is included in to all projects. I think I can use same approach which project "targets", yes? Maybe have some example? And also not sure if it helps (as DLL has info, but "MyApp.exe" does not info...).

Comment: Checked. Including "PropertyGroup" parameters instead of "VersionInfo.cs" file does not help. "MyApp.exe" properties still is not populated, only DLL, so there is no difference using one or another. Not an answer.

Comment: @Drasius "MyApp.exe" is not a managed application it is a native wrapper to boot your managed DLL. That is how .NET Core standalone application are working

Comment: @MikeMazmanyan so there no way to add same version info for executable?

Comment: @Drasius yea, it's just a native wrapper. Why do you need version info with executable ? It's stored within the DLL even if you generate executable.

Comment: @MikeMazmanyan it is not big deal, but mostly you check executable for details. And was interesting is it posiible or not. as when you do full .NET version build which MSBuild all that info is available/set on the executable.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by setting the GenerateAssemblyInfo tag in .csproj to true.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>true</GenerateAssemblyInfo> <!-- this was false -->
...
  </PropertyGroup>
```